# Math.Net FFT Bin Width

Tags: c#, signal-processing, math.net

I am using Math.net to calculate the FFT of some real world data.

This is working as expected, however my real world data can have hundreds of thousands of sample points, resulting in a very narrow bin width in my FFT.

Are there any processes I can use to reduce my number of bins, to say 1000 while still including frequency components from my entire data set.

Rough example of code below.

```
Complex[] comp = input_data.Select(x => new Complex(x, 0)).ToArray();

Fourier.Forward(comp);

mag= comp.Select(c => c.Magnitude).Take(comp.Length / 2).ToArray();
freq = Fourier.FrequencyScale(comp.Length, 1000).Take(comp.Length / 2).ToList();
```

Comment: The bin width is dependent on the sample rate and number of bins. You can only give/take from these variables to alter either. // You may have much better luck on the Signal Processing Stack ( https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple shorter FFTs (sized for the resolution you require), optionally overlap windows, and then combine (average, etc.) the spectrum magnitudes across FFTs.  See [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) and [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method).